# My global variable lastValue doesn't update so I can check if and when 6 is generated twice in a row. thx

Tags: javascript

** As you can see lastValue has a global scope but I don't understand how it doesn't update when returned from the function**

```
let numGenerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)+1;
let lastValue; // undefined ?????

function checkForConsecutiveNumbers() {
    if(lastValue === 6 && numGenerator === 6) {
        console.log("Two 6 in a row");
    }
    lastValue = numGenerator;
};
checkForConsecutiveNumbers();
```

Comment: How do you know it is not updated ? Did you try to do a ```console.log(lastValue)``` after calling ```checkForConsecutiveNumbers()``` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the issue? lastValue does get updated.

```js
let numGenerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)+1;
let lastValue; // undefined ?????

function checkForConsecutiveNumbers() {
    if(lastValue === 6 && numGenerator === 6) {
        console.log("Two 6 in a row");
    }
    lastValue = numGenerator;
};
checkForConsecutiveNumbers();
console.log('After function call. lastValue = ', lastValue)
```

Currently, you are only initializing `numGenerator` once. If you re-initialize it every call to `checkForConsecutiveNumbers` it will log when 6 is generated twice. (For the example I will just force `numGenerator` to always be 6, but replace it with `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)+1`.

```js
let numGenerator;
let lastValue; // undefined ?????

function checkForConsecutiveNumbers() {
  numGenerator = 6; // Re-generate here.
  if (lastValue === 6 && numGenerator === 6) {
    console.log("Two 6 in a row");
  }
  lastValue = numGenerator;
};


checkForConsecutiveNumbers();
checkForConsecutiveNumbers();
```

Adding the random generation back in and just calling it multiple times.

If you run this snippet multiple times, you will see it picks up the sequential 6's.

```js
let numGenerator;
let lastValue; // undefined ?????

function checkForConsecutiveNumbers() {
  numGenerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
  if (lastValue === 6 && numGenerator === 6) {
    console.log("Two 6 in a row");
  }
  lastValue = numGenerator;
};

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  checkForConsecutiveNumbers();
}
```

Comment: Yes that is correct, but If the last random number was 6 I need it to be stored before the function so that if the current random number generated is a 6 again to display "Two 6 in a row"....is that make sense? Thank you

Comment: With this code ```numGenerator``` will never change so there is no point executing the function multiple times. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I want the code to log when 6 (in this case) is generated twice in a row...

Comment: And how could it be ? As ```numGenerator``` is declared once at the beginning and never changed then it will never happen

Comment: You will either need to call `numGenerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)+1` followed by `checkForConsecutiveNumbers`. Or add `numGenerator = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)+1` to `checkForConsecutiveNumbers`.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, I am gonna try to explain this a bit better, so.. when a  number is generated I want that number to be stored in the lastValue variable, if that last number is 6 and the new current random generated number is 6 also the log to the console "Two 6 in a row"

Comment: That is what is happening. Except you are only calling `checkForConsecutiveNumbers` once. Every time you restart the script, everything is re-initialized. This means `lastValue` will be `undefined` again.

Comment: I understand, thank you @Jacob, I am guessing that the solution is to have the value stored in a different file and to reference it from there? What do you think?

Comment: It depends on how you are running this. If you are just running the entire script from start to end, then saving and retrieving it from disk would be reasonable.
However, if you keep the process alive (some sort of loop or demon thread), then the current implementation is sufficient.